# ESP32 bootstrapping / RTS / DTR

Tags: esp32, bootstrap

I am trying to get an ESP-12S to boot/load code from the Arduino environment for the first time on a board of my own, and I am stumped at present. Here's my circuit (with a couple of text notes explaining what I have hacked at so far), does anyone see an obvious mistake I am missing? I am not pressing the button when I try to load code, so that pin (GPIO5) is high. GPIO15 is now also pulled high via a 10k, and R14 is not installed so GPIO12 is low. The only other thing I've seen that I think maybe I should try is putting a cap on GPIO0 so it stays low briefly. Any ideas eagerly awaited!

Update 1: I removed the two NPNs and wired EN to RTS and GPIO0 to DTR. I am now seeing the blue LED on the ESP-12S (by the antenna) flash when the IDE runs esptool.py, but still no download.
[image]

Comment: You want gpio0 held low after reset goes high to enter boot mode. There would have to be a zillion working examples on the internet? As well, your pushbutton switch won’t appreciate trying to discharge a 22uF cap and will die prematurely.

Comment: There are a zillion working examples and at least one nonworking example, which is what I copied, apparently.